# What kind of error is there in C code snippet?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I am examining errors in different C programs and differentiating between them.

Currently, I am confused what type of error is there in this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    in/*hello*/z; 
    double/*world*/y; 
    printf("hello world"); 
    return 0;
}
```

When i run this program, i get compilation error as :

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:4:5: error: unknown type name 'in'
     in/*this is an example*/z; 
     ^
prog.c:5:30: warning: unused variable 'y' [-Wunused-variable]
     double/*is it an error?*/y; 
                              ^
prog.c:4:29: warning: unused variable 'z' [-Wunused-variable]
     in/*this is an example*/z; 
                         ^
```

I know that warning will not prevent from compiling, but there is an error

**error: unknown type name 'in'**

**So, Is this syntax or semantic error ?**

Comment: Did you mean `int` instead of `in`? The error says it can't find type `in` - it's valid syntax but `in` is not a type the compiler knows about. The warnings are to remind you that you haven't used the variables you declared - it's ok not to use them, but then why declare them?

Comment: Are all compile time errors syntax errors by definition? If you wrote `typedef int in;` before `in z;` it would compile. However `int if;` (reserved word `if`) or `5=a;` will never compile. They are different classes of errors to me.

Comment: It is a semantic error.  The syntax is valid, but the semantics require `in` to be a known type, and it is not a known type.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, If possible, Can you please answer why it is semantic error ?

Comment: Several people disagree with me on the subject, but…. It's a semantic error because the code could be valid, but there is a problem with the meaning (semantics) of what is written, because the name `in` isn't a recognized type.  Without changing that line, it would be possible to make the code compile (add `typedef int in;` before it, for example.  In my book, it would be a syntax error if it couldn't be rescued like that.  But, as already noted, opinions seem to vary on this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, That was quite nice explaination to me !!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Can you please refer any book or any standard sources for this . As every program i run, i am confused in the code's semantics . I would be very grateful to you.

Comment: There are two references to 'syntax error' in the C11 standard, both in comments about whether comments are malformed or not.  There is no reference to 'semantic error' in the C11 standard.  The section on diagnostics says that "a conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message … [if a translation unit] contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly
specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be
produced in other circumstances".  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ A typical section such as §6.7 Declarations has some paragraphs labelled 'Syntax' (¶1), 'Constraints' (¶2-4) and 'Semantics' (¶5-7). If the program violates part of the semantics, a diagnostic isn't required, though good compilers do their best to report such errors.  So, there isn't a lot of help (or hindrance) to either view in the standard. You can search the web as well as I can; I'm not going to spend the time finding extra information. You're at liberty to ignore my viewpoint. As I already pointed out, a couple of people say their professors disagree. It's your call.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Even my professor says same thing as you. He also says that its semantic error as the compiler finds no such semantics in the line "in" . Where can I get this translation phases and rules of C standard?

Answer (score 1):

There is obviously a **syntax** error.
First of all we have to clarify a thing: you have to understand clearly what's the difference between *syntax* and *semantics*.
Syntax are the "grammar rules" of a programming language, when the compiler does not compile, you've done syntax errors.
When you do a semantics error you have done a code that compiles successfully, but, when executed does things you do not want to.
C is a strong-typed language: this means that you have to **declare** variables before using them.
You have done a couple of errors, but don't worry, let's analyze them together.
First error: you used a type of variable not possible: and the compiler simply showed it up.
For the "in" type i'm assuming that you meant int, but when you code you have constantly to ask yourself: "Is this variable useful now?"
The answer to this question is: "No", because you just want to make an output.
So the correct implementation of this simple procedure is:

http://groups.engin.umd.umich.edu/CIS/course.des/cis400/c/hworld.html

Hope that this helps.

Bye.

Gerald

Comment: No! Syntactically it is valid; semantically, `in` is an unknown type name.

Comment: Thank you. Our computer science professor always said the opposite.

Comment: Well, I think your professor's semantics are screwed up, but when you answer to him, you'd best do what he expects and if you ever have the misfortune to answer to me, you'd best do what I expect.   On SO, life gets tough.  I think your professor has misled you; he doesn't.  Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

The code does not compile, so this is a syntax error.

A **syntax error** is when the code is not valid at all, and cannot be compiled. Such as trying to declare a variable of a type that does not exist (as in your snippet), or performing an invalid assignment, or many other things.

```
5 = a;
```

That is a syntax error because you cannot assign a value to a number.

```
int if;
```

That is a syntax error because `if` is a keyword that cannot be a variable name.

A **semantic error** is code that is valid and compiles but does not do what you would like. Consider the following simple function to square a number:

```
int square (int value)
{
     return value ^ 2;
}
```

That function does not square the number passed to it but rather performs a bitwise XOR. Yet, in some other languages, `^ 2` would be the syntax to square a number, so this is a semantic error that could conceivably exist in C code.

Comment: No! Syntactically it is valid; semantically, `in` is an unknown type name.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The standard says in 6.7.2 that the syntax of `type-specifier` is one of the standard types (`int`, `double`, etc.) or `struct-or-union-specifier`, `enum-specifier` or `typedef-name`. Since `in` is none of those, I understand that this should be considered a syntax error specifically, though please explain if my reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: Clearly, the compiler recognized from the context that a semantically correct program would have a known type in place of `in`.  In my view, the compiler recognizes that the program could be syntactically correct if the prerequisite declaration of the type `in` were present — and that, in my view, makes it a semantic error and not a syntactic error.  To fix the offending code, it is not necessary to change the syntax of the line the compiler is complaining about (though an easy way to fix it is to edit the line).  All that's necessary is another line that defines a type for the name `in`.

Comment: Equally, it seems there are people who disagree with me.  I disagree with them.  When you report to them, if they're in positions of authority compared to you, you'd best interpret things as they require.  If you ever have the misfortune to report to me, use the nomenclature my way.  On SO, you're stuck between a rock and a hard place.

Comment: My reasoning is that the compiler may be fairly smart, but the standard syntactically requires a `type-specifier` at that position, and there is not one, so this is a syntax error even if the compiler has a good idea how to fix it. While I disagree with you, I'm thankful for your perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is typical typo:

`in/*hello*/z;`

and you wanted `int` type for your variable `z`:

`int /*hello*/ z;`

Comment: What I found interesting about this question is the discovery that `/*world*/` is treated by MSVC as whitespace and so `double/*world*/y;` unexpectedly works.

Comment: Yes, that was a surprise to me too!

Comment: @WeatherVane: I'm surprised you're surprised. Section §5.1.1.2 Translation phases of the standard says: _The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of
white-space characters (including comments). A source file shall not end in a
partial preprocessing token or in a partial comment. Each comment is replaced by
one space character. New-line characters are retained. Whether each nonempty
sequence of white-space characters other than new-line is retained or replaced by
one space character is implementation-defined_ (footnote reference removed). Comment maps to space.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler arcane knowledge indeed.